# How to include a file in sonar lint for analysis if it was excluded?

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I clicked on "exclude" within the sonarlint menuin eclise for a file. Now i can't figure out how to enable it?

the sonarlint analyze option is greyed out for the file now. I tried looking for excluded files at Preferences > SonarLink > File Exclusions, but the file wasn't in the list

[image]

How to remove the file from sonar lint exclusion?

Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

SonarLint version: SonarLint for Eclipse 3.6.0.201806071228

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Follow the below steps,

1. **Properties** of the project folder where you bound the sonar lint.
2. **SonarLint** on the left navigation of the properties for the project
3. **File exclusions**(it shows the file you excluded)
4. **Select** the file in the file exclusions section. just **Remove**

[image]

Again, the respective file is available for sonar lint analysis

If this view is empty for you, than check the project specific settings as described by the comment of pradipgarala.

Comment: But in my case there are no files still it is showing disabled. I tried all possible ways, also I tried uninstalling too but still for that specific file analyze button is disabled.

Comment: Please follow below steps, you will find excluded files. > select project (project explorer) > right click > properties

Answer (score 1):

Remark on where to find the excluded files in IntelliJ:

File > Settings > Other Settings > Sonar Project Settings > File Exclusions